# How to select top 4 records of amount from 2 tables

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables one contain document detail as below :

Table1 : contains customer and total document amount.

```
DocEntry  CustID  CustName  City       DocAmount
1         GF002   Raffy N   London     120.00 
2         GF025   Jhon      Liverpool   50.00
3         GF120   Keng      London     125.25
4         GF055   Tung L.   London      30.00 
5         GF020   Lee H.    Manchester  60.00
```

Table2 : contains item and item price of each document.

```
DocEntry  LineNum  ItemID  ItemName    ItemPrice  Qty  LineAmount
1         0        I0001   Mouse         6.00      5    30.00  
1         1        I0002   Key Broad     6.00      5    30.00 
1         2        I0200   Monitor      60.00      1    60.00 
2         0        I0501   Ext.HDD1     50.00      1    50.00 
3         0        I0665   Printer     125.00      1   125.00
4         0        I0002   Key Broad     6.00      4    24.00
4         1        I0001   Mouse         6.00      1     6.00 
5         0        I0050   ODD          12.00      1    12.00 
5         1        I0001   Mouse         6.00      8    48.00
```

I would like to select the top 3 of documents from Table1 which have highest DocAmount and in the top 3 selected have to show line detail from Table2

the result should be :

```
Row  DocEntry  CustID  CustName DocAmount  ItemID  ItemName    ItemPrice  Qty  LineAmount
1    3         GF120   Keng     125.25     I0665   Printer     125.00      1   125.00
2    1         GF002   Raffy N  120.00     I0001   Mouse         6.00      5    30.00
3    1         GF002   Raffy N  120.00     I0002   Key Broad     6.00      5    30.00 
4    1         GF002   Raffy N  120.00     I0200   Monitor      60.00      1    60.00
5    5         GF020   Lee H.    60.00     I0050   ODD          12.00      1    12.00
5    5         GF020   Lee H.    60.00     I0001   Mouse         6.00      8    48.00
```

Comment: What kind of RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Hi neutrino 
I use SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: and what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select Table2.DocEntry, CustID, CustName, DocAmount, ItemID, ItemName, 
ItemPrice, Qty, LineAmount
from (select top 3 * from Table1 order by DocAmount desc) TopDocs 
    join Table2 on TopDocs.DocEntry=Table2.DocEntry
order by DocAmount desc
```

[SQL Fiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a2cfc/5).